# Redshift number of characters issue

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am facing issue source to target data mapping.

I have source field data - 110242 length charter

```
SELECT MANAGER_REQUEST FROM Table WHERE length(DEAL_MANAGER_REQUEST__C)=110242
```

Redshift max data length is 65000 characters how to handle.

Target is Redshift.

Comment: split the column to multiple smaller columns. sorry no easy workaround for this.

Comment: You could store your binary data as objects in S3 and then store URL references to the S3 objects in your database.